# Let an image appear with key stroke and stay

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I'm currently working on a school project and I'm stuck with this problem.
The problem is in this line of code:

```
   if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]: 
       a = 1
   while a == 1:
       gameDisplay.blit(bulletIMG, (x,y))
```

I know what that problem is, the loop will go on forever.
Is there a way to break out of this loop? or should I try a different approach.

Comment: Yes you can break out of loops using the `break` keyword, and yes you probably do want to try a different approach. You really want a global loop, in which all existing objects display themselves, and also get updated according to user input etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the user press a button and an image displays permanently:

```
display_image = False
while game_running:
    if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        display_image = True
    if display_image:
        gameDisplay.blit(bulletIMG, (x,y))
```

now the image will always be displayed because the flag will always be true once the user hits the space bar (the key is bringing the flag outside the game loop).